# Hot to set PostgreSQL schema for table in Doctrine mapping?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, database-schema

I have two Symfony applications mapped to the same PgSQL database. Both applications use FOSUserBundle so I'm trying to handle users in different schemas. Reading and doing some research on Google I build my entities as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="internal_users", schema="internal")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class InternalUser extends BaseUser
{
    ...
}
```

Then I tried from Symofny2 shell the following:

```
Symfony > doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
The command terminated with an error status (2)
Symfony > doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "14" queries were executed
Symfony >
```

But tables was generated on `public` schema and not in `internal` schema as I want, what I did wrong? Any way to create the tables in different schemas?

Comment: Try to use `@ORM\Table(name="internal.internal_users")`.

Comment: @Salem that works, please post your comment as answer to give your points

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `SCHEMA.TABLE` as table name:

```
@ORM\Table(name="internal.internal_users")
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Doctrine ORM 2.5 you can use the `schema` attribute ([Reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table)):

```
@ORM\Table(schema="internal")
```

Or use `schema` option in yaml driver:

```
App\Entity\InternalUser:
  table: internal_users
  schema: internal
```