# Dockerise Symfony and PostgreSQL database, no datas in prod, Ok in dev

Tags: postgresql, symfony, docker-compose, doctrine-orm

I have a symfony 6.3 web app in docker container (php-fpm-alpine) which used a mysql container.
After migrate mysql database to postgresql, I update .env `DATABASE_URL` to switch to postgresql database and it works fine in dev, it could retrieve datas in database !
I would like to push in production, and if I first don't set correctly the postgresql password (error 500 docker logs return : `connection to server at "my_postgres_service_name" (x.x.x.x), port xxxx failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user`, after set it correctly, I have no more errors… BUT I don't retrieve any datas !

```bash
        php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info returns all entities [OK]
        php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate returns :  

Mapping
-------

 [FAIL] The entity-class App\Entity\Sample mapping is invalid:
 * The field App\Entity\Sample#result is on the inverse side of a bi-directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on the target-entity App\Entity\Result#sample does not contain the required 'inversedBy="result"' attribute.


Database
--------

 [OK] The query yielded an empty result set.
```

After correction :

```
Mapping
-------                                                                                                                      
 [OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                    
Database
--------

[critical] Error thrown while running command "'d:s:v'". Message: "Environment variable not found: "MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN"."

In EnvVarProcessor.php line 187:
                                                              
  Environment variable not found: "MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN".  

2023-10-20T13:21:49+00:00 [info] User Deprecated: The annotation mapping driver is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0, please migrate to the attribute or XML driver. (AnnotationDriver.php:68 called by App_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:1355, https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/10098, package doctrine/orm)
2023-10-20T13:21:49+00:00 [info] User Deprecated: Column::setCustomSchemaOptions() is deprecated. Use setPlatformOptions() instead. (Column.php:424 called by Column.php:92, https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5476, package doctrine/dbal)
```

but in dev, it is always running fine.

I had different version to PHP, so I switched dev and prod to php 8.2.11 without changes regarding my issue

I checked env file, change in *DATABASE_URL* database password -> error 500, put back, no error… but always no datas

I tested a DBAL access *SELECT * FROM an_usual_table* -> ok en dev, error 404 in prod

If I connect to database container `docker exec -it database_postgresql_container psql -U read-write-username database-name` and run above request, it returns correctly records, so used user role have correct permissions

As explain en https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045589/6614155, I tried to add `@ORM\Table(schema="my-schema-name")` in an entity, no change in dev (always run correctly), no change in prod (always no datas)

I also have a postgREST container to have API on postgresql database, with same port in dev and prod.

I spent several days to search and I don't understand. Help welcome !

**EDIT** :
to get rid of symfony and doctrine, I created a file with the minimal code to read a table. If I run it on my dev host, it's fine, but if I run it from my container, I get the error
`Call to undefined function pg_connect()`

phpinfo() return on my (dev) host (php installed with phpbrew to have the same version as in dev/prod) :

```bash
    Configure Command =>  './configure' … '--with-pgsql=/usr/bin' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/bin'

    PDO

    PDO support => enabled 

    PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql pdo_mysql
    pdo_pgsql

    PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled

    PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 14.9
…
```

and in docker php container (dev and prod):

I've got

```bash
    PDO

    PDO support => enabled 

    PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql pdo_mysql
    pdo_pgsql

    PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled

    PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 15.4
```

but no `--with-pdo-pgsql` nor `--with-pgsql` !

Even if I've got in my Dockerfile :

```bash
    RUN apk --no-cache update \ 
    && apk --no-cache add bash icu-dev libzip-dev zip postgresql-dev \ 
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \ 
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \ 
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql intl zip \ 
    && echo "Europe/Paris" > /etc/timezone
```

I change nothing in my php.ini, but I understand correctly, docker-php-ext-configure or install do it

Even if it's a clue, it doesn't explain why it works in dev and not in prod!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests, I run a simple php connection to postgres without using symfony/doctrine, based on https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php and the same issue, no datas, no error.

So I connected to my postgresql container, run

```bash
 \dn
          List of schemas
   Name   |          Owner          
----------+-------------------------
my-schema-name | <user_name>
 public   | postgres
(2 rows)

<my_data_base_name>=# select * from period_list; # request on default schema -> public !!!!
 id | fr_name | gb_name | wiki_data_alignment | bnf_alignment
----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------
(0 rows)

<my_data_base_name>=# select * from my-schema-name.period_list; # if I define my app schema name, I have got correct datas
 id |        fr_name        |       gb_name       | wiki_data_alignment | bnf_alignment
----+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------
  1 | Paléolithique         | Paleolithic         | Q40203              | 
  2 | …
```

and understand than I probably make an error than define same tables in public schema.

SOLUTION:
BE CAREFUL, if you use postgis, postgis default installation uses *public* schema (cf. https://www.postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/schemas.html)

```sql
DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE; # delete public default schema, unused
ALTER DATABASE <my_data_base_name> SET search_path = <my-user-name>,<my-schema-name>
```

The second line is a workaround, I test `@ORM\Table('my-schema-name.my-table')` in SF but not works in prod (perhaps a cache issue)… I should find the right solution to define schema in SF.

link about default schema that help me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/6614155